# Azure VM RHEL Custom Script Extension: script.sh not found error

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rhel

I've been trying to deploy a custom script extension to a RHEL VM in Azure. The script just contains 'mkdir testfolder'. And 'command to execute' is 'sh script.sh'. I keep getting an error 'script.sh can not be found'.

How do I properly execute custom script Extension in RHEL Azure VM?

On the menu blade of a RHEL azure vm, selected extensions, then chose custom script extensions from the list of extensions, then uploaded the shell script file(script.sh), and in command to execute: sh script.sh

Comment: show us how you invoke it

Comment: I've editted the question to show how I am invoking it.

Comment: looks okay. can you login to the vm and search if the script gets uploaded?

Comment: Yeah, I logged into the VM using the account I created while deploying the machine. When I "ls" the folder in which I am logged, I can't see the file. But I can see the file in a different path.

Comment: yeah, its supposed to be on a different path, not in your home directory. are you sure the case is correct?

Comment: Yes I am sure about that. Carefully named the shell script and command to execute. Multiple times.

Comment: Also, I've tried this on multiple RHEL machines and multiple shell scripts with different filenames.

Comment: this looks fine, cant see why this would not work, sorry. cant help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux

Comment: Use the full path to the script

Comment: You can show the whole steps and it's helpful to find out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the test follow the steps you posted. And it works well in my side. The result here:

**script.sh**

[image]

customExtension

[image]

execute in the vm:

[image]

So you should check if your script name is same as the command `sh script.sh`. The error "script.sh can not be found" just shows the reason.

Comment: Thank you Charles. I am new to Linux, so was messing up with paths and case sensitive names.